# 400 Bad Request while trying to add a user to a group using ShP 2013 REST api

Tags: 2013, rest

I am having such a bad time trying to figure this out. I'm trying to add a user to a group by posting to:

```
_api/web/sitegroups(8)/users
```

The posted data looks like this:

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName' : 'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }
```

I get Bad Request 400 and I have no idea what is wrong.

```
public void AddUserToGroup()
            {
                string requestPath = "/_api/web/sitegroups(8)/users";
                string userPostBody = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }";
                ExecuteAuthorizedPostRequest(requestPath, userPostBody);
            }

        private HttpWebResponse ExecuteAuthorizedPostRequest(string requestPath, string postBody)
        { 
            string formDigestValue = GetFormDigestValue();
            HttpWebRequest request = PreparePostRequest(requestPath, formDigestValue, postBody);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            return response;
        }

        private HttpWebRequest PreparePostRequest(string requestPath, string formDigestValue, string postBody)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + requestPath);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.ContentLength = postBody.Length;

            byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            return request;
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the respone message content? I think it might be helpful for you. If you are uncertain where to find it consider using Fiddler, Wireshark or similar.

Comment: @robert-lindgren did you just accidentally solve the question when cleaning/editing it (adding tow backslashes)? :D

Comment: @eirikb, sorry but the double-backslashes was there all the time (but not visible due to invalid markup) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is your friend. If you watch the traffic (response) you see the real error message:

> Invalid JSON. An unrecognized escape sequence '\u' was found in a JSON string value.

(where 'u' is the first character of the user name)

You should double-escape the backslash `\`, once for C# and once for JSON. That means `i:0#.w|domain\\\\user` (four backslashes!) instead of `i:0#.w|domain\\user` (two backslashes). The same is true for JavaScript.

The posted data should be (two backslashes!):

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName' : 'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }
```

Comment: You are welcome! I'm more than happy that my suggestion helped. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'll just add this as an alternative:
If you serialize the JSON, e.g., with [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), you would not have stumbled upon the problem @pholpar pointed out to you.

Like this:

```
string loginName = ...;
var postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    __metadata = new
    {
        type = "SP.User"
    },
    LoginName = loginName
});
```

Comment: For what it is worth, the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class that is part of the System.Web.Extensions assembly creates identical JSON in this case without a third party dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, according to [Using WCF Data Service With Restricted Characters as Keys](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx):

> the symbols `%,&,*,:,<,>,+,#, /, ?,\` are considered as "special" in
>   WCF Data Service

In order to avoid such kind of errors, the serialization of POCO is commonly used.

### Examples

```
var loginName = "i:0#.w|domain\\user";

var userPayload = new
{
      __metadata = new
      {
         type = "SP.User"
      },
      LoginName = loginName
};
```

**Using JSON.NET**

```
var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userPayload);
```

**Using JavaScriptSerializer**

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var postData = serializer.Serialize(userPayload);
```

Comment: I just have to ask; how is restricted characters for WCF related to post body in REST? You don't need to escape them in the post body. Maybe if you use them as keys in a JSON object, but I don't even know how to test that (and that is not what OP has anyway)

Comment: @eirikb, thank you for the comment! ..because if you take a look at the property LoginName in postBody string after the serialization (at your example it is at line: postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject) you will notice that the value is escaped

Comment: Yeah ok now I see what you mean. JSON itself will of course use backslash to escape (ref `JSON.stringify('\\')`). But still, the link you provide is about URLs and URIs and not post body, and not even JSON, which is why I was confused :)